# Camera is not working in ASUS Zenfone2

Tags: rooting, camera, asus-zenfone-2

While opening camera in my asus zenfone2, it shows a black screen and suddenly exit from camera application (The device got authorized service from asus twice, and after second service, the problem arised. May be due to camera driver errors). Everything functions perfectly except camera. So, I am trying to root the phone and need to install cyanogen-mod in my device. Does this operation solves camera error? Please, tell me how to root and install(TWRP) recovery in asus.

Comment: Have you tried opening your camera in a different application? (ex. Google Camera?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Backup is important**

1. flash Stock ROM again.
2. Root the device, install a custom Recovery(TWRP), and install a custom ROM(Eg: Cyanogenmod or mokee or aicp etc) URL to XDA is descibed below :

[XDA Zenfone2](https://forum.xda-developers.com/zenfone2)

How to Root and [Install TWRP](http://www.stechguide.com/root-and-install-twrp-recovery-on-asus-zenfone-2/) is described on this link.

How to flash:

**Check for any firmware file required, before flashing ROM. Otherwise, your device will get bricked.**

```
a. Install latest TWRP recovery on your device.
b. Make a backup of your current ROM.
c. Wipe system, data, cache and dalvik.
d. Flash ROM and Google apps.
e. Reboot system.
Custom ROM is installed.
```